# How to successfully receive Google Drive v3 Push Notifications using python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, push-notification, google-drive-api

I have completed the steps provided by Google to implement [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push) using the Drive API.  Everything goes as described except I do not receive any notifications from Google whenever a change occurs (listed as Step 4 below).

Below is a summary of the steps I followed and the results at each stage:

**Step 1 (Success)**: Verify that you own the domain

I went to Search Console as directed and successfully verified the site.

**Step 2 (Success)**: Register your domain

I visited the Domain Verification page and added my domain in the API Console.  Google API Console updated to show the list with my desired domain.

I have a valid SSL certificate from GoDaddy for my domain and have verified that as well.

**Step 3 (Success)**: Created my notification channel

Using the python SDK, I created the channel and got back a response from Google.  The python code below shows how I did this. Note: The address included in my request directs Google to send notifications to my Flask website that I am hosting in Google's App Engine.  I am showing the domain as my_domain.com here for privacy as I am in the process of bringing up the site.

```
channel_id = str(uuid.uuid4())

body = {
    'kind': 'api#channel',
    'id': channel_id,
    'type': 'web_hook',
    'address': "https://my_domain.com/notifications"
}


try:
    start_page_token = service.changes().getStartPageToken().execute().get('startPageToken');
    print(service.changes().watch(pageToken=start_page_token, body=body).execute())
except Exception as e: 
    print('Exception: {}'.format(e))
```

And here is the response from Google:

```
{u'resourceId': u'vTMwJWl7a23Af1LK1TpJZ38eO_0', u'kind': u'api#channel', u'expiration': u'1538433975000', u'id': u'dce14225-95c8-42a7-9945-4fed1604c848', u'resourceUri': u'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes?alt=json&includeCorpusRemovals=false&includeRemoved=true&includeTeamDriveItems=false&pageSize=100&pageToken=4919&restrictToMyDrive=false&spaces=drive&supportsTeamDrives=false&alt=json'}
```

**Step 4 (Failed)**: Process a notification from Google

I am running a Flask website on App Engine and created an app.route to receive notifications from Google.  I've included the code below.  I never receive anything at this URL.

```
@app.route('/notifications')
def notifications():
    print('in notifications()')

    try:
        chan_id = request.args.get('X-Goog-Channel-ID', 'empty')
        msg_num = request.args.get('X-Goog-Message-Number', 'empty')
        rid = request.args.get('X-Goog-Resource-ID', 'empty')
        state = request.args.get('X-Goog-Resource-State', 'empty')  
        resource_uri = request.args.get('X-Goog-Resource-URI', 'empty') 
        goog_changed = request.args.get('X-Goog-Changed', 'empty')
        goog_chan_exp = request.args.get('X-Goog-Channel-Expiration', 'empty')
        goog_chan_token = request.args.get('X-Goog-Channel-Token', 'empty')

        print('chan_id: {}'.format(chan_id))
        print('msg_num: {}'.format(msg_num))
        print('rid: {}'.format(rid))
        print('state: {}'.format(state))
        print('resource_uri: {}'.format(resource_uri))
        print('goog_changed: {}'.format(goog_changed))
        print('goog_chan_exp: {}'.format(goog_chan_exp))
        print('goog_chan_token: {}'.format(goog_chan_token))


    except Exception as e:
        print('notifications() exception: {}'.format(e))

    print('leaving notifications()')

    return jsonify(result='done')
```

Comment: Could you provide the logs?

Comment: The only log relevant here would be the AppEngine app log for my Flask instance.  I have reviewed it and there are no entries at all associated with the target address where I have requested to receive notifications from Google.

Comment: Over a period of 2 days, I never received any evidence in my GAE log files of any requests made to my desired receiving address.  Just today, I received my first entry in the logs which has now helped me to complete the full process.  For any Flask users, once I did get log entries, I needed to add the appropriate method to my route (POST) to process the incoming message.  I have no idea why there were no traces in my log files showing the APIs-Google user agent.  I am leaving this as unanswered for now.  I hope to ultimately get more answers and will post when I do.

Comment: did you figure it out in the end? having the same issue

Comment: Unfortunately, I was never able to determine exactly why the initial problem occurred (or why it started working).  I inquired with Google but did not get a definitive answer.  Ultimately, I had to move on due to project deadlines.  All I can say is that I worked through the process from the first step multiple times to verify my configurations.  If you discover more detail related to the lack of notifications, please post here to help others avoid the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the problem but, when I tried Google Drive push notifications, I didn't use the SDK. I only made a POST request as it shows in the documentation.

Could you try to make a POST request to `"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/watch"` instead of using `service.changes().watch()`?

You will need an `access_token` for the request, but I believe you wont need to send a `startPageToken` as they don't use it in their example:
[image: example]

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I reworked my code and tried this approach with the same result.  Even though it is not documented in the example, the response from my POST request indicates that the pageToken is indeed required.  I added it as a parameter to my POST and, as the example states, I do receive a 200 OK from the call with the expected response values.  Unfortunately, I still receive nothing at the specified web_hook address that I provided.  Not even the sync message that should be sent immediately per the docs.

Comment: As a follow up, I also tested the HTTP POST approach by supplying a web_hook address to a known bad address.  When I do so, Google responds with: Unauthorized WebHook callback channel.  So it appears that Google is not having an issue with the address that I am providing when I give it my known GOOD address.

Comment: I see.. so it seems you are doing it right, pretty strange that you don't receive messages. Anyways I also see on a comment above that you have started to receive messages finally :)

FYI: Don't know if you tried, but when I tried push notifications I did it with changes from files instead of 'all changes', so I don't know if there is a problem with changes endpoint